# C# - Create class instance inside another class with same meaning

Tags: c#, instance

I want to create a class named `Enemy`, which should be used in a programmed rpg-themed-battlesystem. The problem is that I would want to create multiple monster types in the `Enemy` class, but then I would have to create a possibility for the battlesystem with every enemy class for example `Enemy.Goblin` or `Enemy.Golem`.
**Question:**
How could I achieve this by using only one parameter in the battlesystem function? I wanted to use

```
public static void InitiateBattle ( Player player, Enemy enemy )
```

but now I cannot use the `Enemy.Goblin` instance, because it cant implicitly convert `Enemy.Goblin` to `Enemy`. How could I most easily and with minimal code fix this?

Comment: Read about class inheritance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
public class Enemy
{
 // put all properties and methods common to all here
}

public class Goblin: Enemy
{
  // goblin specific stuff here
}
```

you will then be able to pass in a goblin as an enemy.

Comment: What about properties like Healthpoints, how would I be able to call/set these?

Comment: @IanH. they would go in the enemy class since all enemies have hp.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use inheritance?

```
public class Enemy {}
public class Goblin : Enemy {}
public class Golem : Enemy {}
```

You can then pass in an instance of `Goblin` or `Golem` to your method and the statement will be valid because the compiler will 'box' your object into an instance of the parent type.

Then, if you want to use a member from the Goblin or Golem subclasses, you would need to 'cast' the `enemy` parameter variable back into the appropriate type using `as`:

```
public static void InitiateBattle (Player player, Enemy enemy)
{
     var golem = enemy as Golem;
     var goblin = enemy as Goblin;
}
```

Make sure you check for null after the cast!

Bear in mind that C# does not allow multiple-inheritance; each class can inherit from only one parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to use interface.

```
public interface IEnemy
{
    //e.g.
    public void Attack();
}

public class Goblin : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Battle
{
    public static void InitiateBattle(Player player, IEnemy enemy);
}
```